# How to specify more than one option in jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using [jQuery Datepicker](http://www.jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#default). I am using follwing script to attach the datepicker to all controls whose class is datepicker.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ showButtonPanel: true});
  });
  </script>
```

Now, is it possible to use more than one option while creating the datepicker, like this

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({ showButtonPanel: true}, {showOtherMonths: true });
```

It doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({ showButtonPanel: true, showOtherMonths: true });
```

This is a common idiom in jQuery, to use a JSON object (hash) for the options.

Comment: and what's that: `hash vs options`

Comment: options `object` or options `object hash` are two terms for describing the same thing. The Hash part stems from `Hash table` as far as I am aware, where each property has a key (its name) and a value. Think of the `object hash` as JavaScript's version of an associative array, if it helps.

Comment: This is just standard json, I think calling it a hash is very misleading.  The difference is that datepicker takes in one object. that one object should contain all options to set. the above question gives it an object for each option.

Answer (score 3):

One of the parameters to most jQuery plugins accepts an object as the argument, for example `{ option1: 'optionValue'}`. This allows the user to pass in whichever options that they want to change from the defaults. In most plugins, this options object is then merged with the default options using `$.extend()`, overriding any of the default options with properties from the options object if they are defined.

One of the usual ways a plugin is written is as follows

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {

    var settings = $.extend({  // these are the default properties
                               option1: 'default value',
                               option2: true,
                               option3: 5437
                            }, 
                            // merge with the options object passed in
                            // or an empty object
                            options || {});

    // now we can use the settings object in our plugin, which will have
    // property values from the settings object and the options object passed in


    }

})(jQuery);
```

the `options || {}` part in `$.extend()` guards against a false value being passed for `options`. The order of the objects in `$.extend()` determines which properties take precendence- a property defined on an object will have it's value *replaced (use the term roughly here)* by the same property name declared on a later object.